# Writing matlab matrix to excel

Tags: excel, matlab, export

I am trying to export a matrix from Matlab to export with xlswrite. However, my matrix is a cellarray that has strings such as '001', '00323'. When it is exported into Excel, Excel automatically converts them back to numbers and drops the first 2 zeros into '1', and '323'.

Does anyone know how to force excel to accept them as Text as them are being written from Matlab to xlsx?

Thank you!
L.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel probably likes to do this because it is exactly what Excel would do if you typed those values in.
One way to fix this is to put `'"=001"'` in the cell array rather than `'001'` like the following code. Note that Excel treats the values properly in the resulting file:

```
myCell= {1, '0001', '="0001"'};
xlswrite('test.xlsx', myCell)
```

You could write a little function that surrounds all the strings in a cell array with quotes, if needed:

```
function aCell = fixForExcel(aCell)

    for ind = 1:numel(aCell)
        myVal = aCell{ind};

        if isstr(myVal)
            aCell{ind} = sprintf('="%s"', myVal)
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue with SSNs. I don't know how much control you have with creating the spreadsheet with xlswrite.

You can set the format to Text, and this preserves the leading zeroes.

The problem will remain that when you open the spreadsheet, all leading zeroes will be eliminated. You can create a custom format that specifies that the format for the cell has two leading zeroes. You can use "\0\0#" as your custom expression. The text format will be saved after the first time.

If you have a variable number of 0s, the only way to get around it is to copy the data into excel.